# Hide/Show button in React Native Toolbar

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to hide/show a button in header of a React Native Toolbar. I would like the buttons to show once the user logs in. I get the error undefined is not an object on this.state.status. How can I get the state in the toolbar?

```
export default class TestSC extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state ={
      status:false
    }
  }


  static navigationOptions = ({navigation})=> {
    return {
    title: 'Tin Tin Foil',
     headerRight: ( 
      <View style={styles.twoButtonView}>
         {(this.state.status == true) ?  
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._refreshButtonPress}>
            <Image source={require('../img/ic_search_white.png')} style={styles.refrgeshButton}  />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        : null} 
        <Button
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')}
          title="Login" color="#fff" />
      </View>
    ),
  }};

  toggleStatus(){
    this.setState({
      status:!this.state.status
    });
    console.log('toggleStatus: '+ this.state.status);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Test</Text>

          <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>this.toggleStatus()}>
            <Text> Click Me Toggle </Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `navigation params` to achieve this.

While setting component state, you need to set Navigator params as well.

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({
    status: true
})
```

And use navigator params in the header.

```
navigation.state.params.status == true
```

Complete Example

```
export default class TestSC extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      status: false
    }
  }

  static navigationOptions = ({navigation, screenProps}) => {  
    if (!navigation.state.params) {
      navigation.state.params = {}
    }
    return {
      title: 'Tin Tin Foil',
      headerRight: ( 
        <View style={styles.twoButtonView}>
          {(navigation.state.params.status == true) ?  
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._refreshButtonPress}>
              <Text>Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          : null}
        </View>
      ),
    }
  };

  toggleStatus() {
    this.setState(pre => {
      pre.status = !pre.status
      this.props.navigation.setParams({
        status: pre.status
      })
      return pre
    })

    console.log('toggleStatus: ' + this.state.status);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Test</Text>

          <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>this.toggleStatus()}>
            <Text> Click Me Toggle </Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am new to React Native and have been struggling with this issue for a while.  I changed the condition line to "{(navigation.state.params != null &&  navigation.state.params.status == true) ? "   I think params was null when the page first loaded.